# How to check if the edit mode in jstree is on? Is it possible to check it?

Tags: jstree

I am using jsTree and I want to get the name/value/text of the node I just created so that I can pass it and store it in the database.
My problem is that after enabling the edit mode, I have no wayof getting the value entered by the user.
My idea is that if I can only determine if the edit mode is on or off, then I can kinda run a function that will now get the user's input. I included here the function for creating the node.

Any other way to solve this problem is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function demo_create(){
            var ref = $('#data').jstree(true),
            p_id = sel = ref.get_selected();
            console.log("Parent Id: "+p_id);   
            if(!sel.length) { return false; }
            sel = sel[0];
            id = sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});
            console.log("Newly Created Id: "+id);
            if(sel) {
                ref.edit(sel);
            }
        };
```

Comment: @vakata Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`edit` will fire the `rename_node.jstree` once the node name is changed.

You can also use the callback of `edit`:

```
ref.edit(sel, null, function (node, status) {
    console.log(node.text); // the new node title
})
```

Comment: I don't know how to use the callback of edit in getting the new value entered by the user. Any idea on how to get around with that?

Comment: If you want to react to the user changing the title - use the `create_node.jstree`. If you insist on using the `edit` callback - you can get the new title from `node.text`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hit the "mark useful" at the left but it says that until I cannot gain 15 reputation then I think I cannot change the displayed score.

Comment: Maybe you can accept the answer itself? If not - no problem :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that tool. I'm really new here. Done. :D Thanks again! You're heaven sent!

Comment: @vakata I think you mean "rename_node.jstree" in your comment. didn't you ?